# LaTeX + git - sharing a repository?

Tags: git, latex, bitbucket

I'm using git for the first time to manage a collaborate LaTeX project.  I have set up a local git repository, and committed it to bitbucket using ssh.  So far, all good.

My collaborator has never used git either, and has asked me for advice.  I know he can clone the repository.  But I don't know if the repository, once cloned, is automatically tracked by git.  So what I need to know is: what do I tell my collaborator for him to have the repository on his local computer set up in such a way as to be automatically tracked by git, and so that he can commit changes whenever he makes them?

Comment: All your friend need do is install Git locally and then clone the repository.  After doing this, Git will track his changes and he can pull and commit to the same shared branch which you are already using.

Comment: If you want him to able to push changes back to your repository on BitBucket, you need to give him "write" permissions there. Alternately, he could make his own repository there too (a "fork") and you can pull from that.

Comment: When you say "I know he can clone the repository", does that mean he actually has cloned it? Because if he has, then it is tracked in git by definition and yes he can commit changes whenever he makes them. He will still need to `push` those commits back to Bitbucket so that you can see them though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Tell him, if he did a clone of your repository, he can also commit locally to track his changes. But to send you the changes he has to use `git push`. And he gets your changes as updates by using `git pull`.

You said "automatically". To be clear here: Git is tracking but you need to commit your changes locally by using the `git commit` command.

If you want him to be able to send you his changes, you need to give him write permission to the repo on Bitbucket and he has to push the changes up to bitbucket after committing them locally.

`git commit` is local.
`git push` command sends changes to an remote location.
see also git-remote and [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

If he cloned from bitbucket, `git remote -v` should show bitbucket as origin. Then a simple git push should work. If `git remote -v` does not show the origin, check [adding a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response.  I sort of understood that this was the way it was meant to work, but when my collaborator tried to clone the repository he got errors:

Permission denied (publickey).
Fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Does this mean he needs his own public/private key pair for use with bitbucket/git, or have I done something wrong?  (This is getting seriously frustrating.  I don't think I've ever had so many things go wrong with a system. I know it's just me, but it appears that git is set up to be deliberately difficult).

Comment: I've tried to do it with https, following the instructions at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes  However, I seem to be able to create a remote repository, but I can neither clone to it nor push to it: "git origin -v" shows that the repository is available, but attempts to clone into it or push to it produce errors: "remote: Not Found" and 
"fatal: repository ... not found".  Aargh.  How DO people use this?  Why is it so difficult?

Comment: Tell him to also create an account at bitbucket and you have to create a team. Then enter his email adress or username as teammember. And after that he can use his username and credentials to push/pull from/to your repository. Or did you add the repository as public?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation about teams](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-teams-321853005.html)?